# Is __main__ guaranteed to always be importable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

Is there any case where doing:

```
import __main__
```

might lead to an `ImportError`? All cases I've tried seem to indicate that this always works. The docs on [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) don't seems to state anything on the matter.

To give some context: I am trying to inject some names in `__main__.__dict__` using the `usersitecustomize` hook in order to (mainly) have them available when the REPL fires up.

Granted that no redefinitions of `__import__` occur (as a comment stated), this essentially boils down to if I need to wrap it in a `try-except` or not.

Comment: Sure, for example if you [replace `__import__`](http://ideone.com/gFuzwp), but I doubt that's the kind of thing you're looking for. What specific failure types are you interested in?

Comment: Try printing `__main__` in A.py and then importing A in B.py.

Comment: What are you guys talking about? `__main__` isn't always the current module; it's the namespace in which the main script executes, or in which interactive code executes in interactive mode.

Comment: @user2357112 After looking back at the docs, I agree. My previous comment was erroneous. I'll remove it.

Comment: @user2357112 granted that no sneaky stuff like that occur. I'm looking to inject some names in `__main__.__dict__` during start-up (`usersitecustomize`) to have them available without the need to import them. I'm not sure if I should wrap it in a try or not.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm not sure I understand. I'm importing `__main__` for the reasons I stated in the previous comment. Could you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @BobHolver Oh, sorry. I was just trying to say that that doesn't throw any errors. Anyway, you could also query `globals()`, it returns the same thing and you don't have to import anything.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Unless my script is executing as `__main__` (in which case, `__main__.__dict__` gets updated and all is ok) that will unfortunately won't work as Blckknght highlighted.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Despite it's name, the `globals` namespace is not the same everywhere in a program. It's just the current module's top level namespace (and so global relative to the local namespaces of any functions the module contains). Each module (including `__main__`) has its own globals.

Comment: If you look at the standard `site` module, you'll see that it injects things (like `quit` and `credits`) into the `builtins` module instead of into `__main__`. I'm not sure if that's the best way to make your objects available in the REPL, but there's precedent for that approach.

Comment: @Blckknght hadn't seen that. `builtins` is initialized early in CPython (at least) afaik so that does seem like an approach that wouldn't fail. Still curious about the availability of `__main__`, though :-)

Answer (score 3):

It probably is. Python initializes `__main__` in this file:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pylifecycle.c#L1327

However please note that modules like `runpy` and `IPython` replace the `__main__` module with their own dynamically created ones to prevent collisions with their own launch scripts and to provide expected behaviour in case of runpy.

runpy itself is part of the Python Standard Library and provides the implementation of the `-m` flag which allows arbitrary modules to be executed as script.

An alternative is IPython which offers the feature to execute code at the launch of a new REPL.

For more details, see here: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html?highlight=exec_lines